# Insert href, but prevent redirection and 'market' call in FF (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, redirect

I need to send request to some url. But this url may contain redirection (302) to market:// . In this case Firefox in Android opens Play Market and it's bad.

How can we prevent market opening in FF?

Script looks like this:

```
function addIframe(url) {
  var elHead, elLink;
  elLink = document.createElement('link');
  elLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
  elLink.type = 'text/css';
  elLink.href = url;
  elHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  elHead.appendChild(elLink);
}
```

Comment: Any sample `url` What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Thanks. This one for example: https://admin.appnext.com/appLink.aspx?b=32910&e=93758&tid=AWLPtest&vid=AWLP_test